# how to run J48 with with different amount of attributes

Tags: weka

Rank the attributes based on their OneR performance – To do this click on the “Select attributes” tab. select the method as “OneR attribute evaluator”. List the attributes in the ranked order.
Run Decision Tree (J48 in weka) with only one attribute (the best attribute), then with first two, then with three and so on…
List the accuracy (f-measure) corresponding to each case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks a little like homework, so I'll try to answer the general parts so you can apply the rest for yourself.

You will need to use an [AttributeSelectedClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/AttributeSelectedClassifier.html) as your classifier, which is in the meta section of your classifiers.  This allows you to filter out the unwanted attributes before running the classifier.

From there, you will need to set up your classifier type (J48), evaluator and search methods to limit the number of attributes.